# Crystal Report Error in Formula : "A Variable name is expected here"

Tags: crystal-reports, report, filtering

I am using Crystal Report version 2016 (14.2.6.2839).
and getting an error while performing filter by "Parameter fields".
In following code{?ParamXYZ}is prompt parameter.

```
NumberVar Counter; 
For Counter:=1 to UBound({?ParamXYZ})do 
(
if({?ParamXYZ}[Counter] IN {Table1.Column1})
then true
else false
);
```

Please note: Formula editor is not giving me an error, after exiting from formula editor screen, getting an error in "Select Expert-Record popup"
Please see below image error pointing on "Counter variable" at FOR
Help will be appreciated a lot..!!

[image]

Comment: Where is this variable ?ParamXYZ declared? This formula exists in Sub Report?

Comment: as mentioned, a variable is pointing to 'Counter' and there are no subreports, this formula is used for filtering - @ItiTyagi